# The composition of inversions of two non-intersecting circles is hyperbolic

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

I am solving a question from Gareth A. Jones book *Complex Functions.* The question is:

> (i) Show that the circle
> \begin{equation}\label{1}
>     a z \bar{z}+\bar{b} \bar{z}+b z+c=0 \quad(a, c \in \mathbb{R})
> \end{equation}
> (ii) Deduce that the composition of two inversions $I_{C_{1}}{\circ} I_{C_{2}}$ is hyperbolic if the circles $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$ do not intersect. Show that the composition of the above two inversions is parabolic if $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$ touch and elliptic if $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$ intersect in two points.

To solve (ii), one may assume that $C_2=\mathbb{R},$ and use (i). Here's my solution:

Let $C_2=\mathbb{R}.$ Then, $I_\mathbb{R}$ is given by complex conjugation. Let $C_1$ be the circle given by
$$a z \bar{z}+\bar{b} \bar{z}+b z+c=0 \quad(a, c \in \mathbb{R})\quad\dots (1)$$
then, $I_{C_1}$ be given by the mapping $$z\mapsto \frac{-\bar{b}\bar{z}-c}{a\bar{z}+b}.$$
*This is the general form of any inversion for the circle with equation (1).*

Then, we have that $$A=I_{C_1}\circ I_\mathbb{R}:z\mapsto \frac{-\bar{b}z-c}{az+b}.$$
Now, $A\in PGL(2,\mathbb{C});$ let $B$ be the matrix representation of $A$ in $PSL(2,\mathbb{C}).$ Then, as $det(\lambda A)=\lambda^n det(A),$ we have that
$$B=\frac{1}{\sqrt{ac-|b|^2}}A=\frac{1}{\sqrt{ac-|b|^2}}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}
    -\bar{b}       & -c \\
    a      & b
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Now, $A$ is hyperbolic if $tr^2(B)>4,$ i.e., if $$(b-\bar{b})^2=b^2+\bar{b}^2-2|b|^2>4(ac-|b|^2).$$ Simplifying, we see that $A$ is hyperbolic if $$(b+\bar{b})^2=4(\Re(b))^2>4ac,$$ i.e. if $(\Re(b))^2>ac.$

--

This is exactly the opposite of what is needed, that is, what I needed to show was that if $A$ is hyperbolic, then $(\Re(b))^2<ac.$

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, I believe I have misplaced a minus sign or have done a really terrible error.

Help will be extremely appreciated! If there is any information that is further required, please ask!

Comment: For $C_1$ to be a real circle, you need $|b|^2-ac>0$.

Comment: By a real circle, what do exactly mean?

Comment: A circle with positive radius.

Comment: So you are saying that $B=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|b|^2-ac}}A?$ But then won't $B$ have determinant $-1?$

Comment: Using your formula, you can check that ${\rm det}(B)=1$ but the inequality should be reversed: $${\rm tr}^2(B)>4\Leftrightarrow (b-\overline{b})^2<4(ac-|b|^2),$$ since $ac-|b|^2<0.$

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes it all clear!